# How does the 'Window' run command work in terms of interpreting file extensions

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I was wondering if anybody is aware about the mechanics behind how the RUN command sees extenions?

For example, when executing the run command (WIN + R key), for batch files I don't need to type the full name (file name + including the extensions), but other files I do need to.

In other words, if there is a batch file called ABC.bat and a Python file called XYZ.py, why can I type ABC only in the RUN application and the batch file will run. For Python, I need to type the entire XYZ.py. It's not a major problem, but would like to be able to do the same thing for Python files (i.e. just type XYZ and the script will execute)

Note, the batch files and python files are under the same folder, and of course the folder is setup properly in the %PATH% environment so the RUN command will see it. I'm using the Windows 10 environment.

Comment: Take a look at `%PATHEXT%`

Comment: Win+R does not use `PATHEXT`. If you attach a debugger you'll see it calls `shell32!ShellExecCmdLineWithSite`. This checks many things, one of which is to call `shlwapi!ApplyDefaultExts` to look for the filename plus what appears to be a hard-coded list of default extensions: .pif, .com, .exe, .bat, .lnk and .cmd.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I posted my message but looks like it didn't show up. Just wanted to say thank you for the response. Now I understand how the logic works.